# #value error mac excel 2016 array formula

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm getting a #value error in Excel 2016 on a mac.

Formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF('Instructional RAW'!$C:$C,'Lead Teacher (42)'!$E$12,IF('Instructional RAW'!$G:$G,'Lead Teacher (42)'!E$28,'Instructional RAW'!$R:$R)))
```

Adding dummy data:

```
Job Code    Average Salary  Type
42  $60,000 Single site
42  $26,000 Single site
42  $26,500 Multi site
40  $62,000 Single site
49  $40,000 Multi site
42  $45,000 Multi site
21  $33,000 Single site
43  $30,000 Multi site
42  $51,500 Single site
```

Desired outcome: calculate the median salary based on a set of conditions - job code = 42, school type = single site.

When clicking ctrl+shift+enter, I get the value error. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you supply some test data and expected result? And do you really need entire column references?

Comment: No, I don't. Maybe that is what is causing the error... I'll look into it.

Comment: I don’t think that is the source of the error. It might be an unexpected datatype in one of the ranges perhaps. Is an actual median possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do with IF's? Your if condition does not look like a condition. Do you have TRUE, FALSE values in column C and G?

Comment: What I'd like to do is calcuate the median salary based on a number of conditions. Updating the original post with dummy data and desired outcomes.

Comment: @MehmetYusufÇakmak  updated above. thoughts ?

Comment: your formula looks fine. Is there something about the data? Are you sure you entered properly so {} appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following formula where A column has Job Type, B column has Average Salary and C column has Salary Type should work.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A2:A10=42,IF(C2:C10="Single site",B2:B10,""),""))
```

Apply the formula using ctrl + shift + enter.

Also be sure that Average Salary is in a numeric format (number, currency etc.).

Comment: Thank you! THis solved it. I also had to convert job code to numeric.